# Why is my delegated event handler not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button with id of `Strike` but the JQUERY event doesn't seem to work? This event here worked previously, but ONLY if the button existed when the DOM loaded.

```
dom.el('Strike').onclick = strikeSkill;
```

Now I have my buttons dynamically generated, so the "Strike" button is generated later. So the previous code above no longer works, because Strike = `Null`.

I am using the Jquery .on function, filled up my arguments, but now when I click the strike button, nothing happens. No attacking. Why is this?

```
function strikeSkill() {
    activeCheck();
    if (upgradeActive == true){
        radialSelector(strike);
    }   
    if (upgradeActive == false){
        HitCalc(player.cc, monster.cc);
        actor.expCounter(player.cc);
        actor.balanceCounter(player.cc, monster.cc);
    }
};

$('#Strike').on('click', '#Strike', function() {
    strikeSkill();
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ Use this for dynamically generated elements.

Comment: How are u adding buttons dynamically ? Through jQuery?

Answer (score 3):

Your current event handler is looking for a `#Strike` element *within* `#Strike`, which is incorrect (not to mention would be invalid HTML).

You can fix this by using a static parent element for the primary selector:

```
$(document).on('click', '#Strike', function(){
    strikeSkill();
});
```

In the example I used the `document`, however for best performance it should be the nearest static parent element to `#Strike` which is available when the DOM loads.

Comment: Do you happen to know if there's any reports on how which parent you chose to delegate from, affects the performance? like using Document vs using a static parent directly above the dynamic element? I only understand it as a rule of thumb

Comment: @NachoDawg I don't, but it can be easily tested - http://jsperf.com. I would imagine the difference is tiny; probably tens of miliseconds - but no reason not to optimise for best performance. The difference is simply in the number of elements the event has to bubble through before being caught.